# JWplayer transparent screencolor parameter

Tags: flash, transparency, flv, jwplayer

I have FLV file encoded with VP6 flash 8 with alpha.
When changing the screencolor parameter in the JWPlayer setup I can see the movie in different background colors (on the transparent part).
However, I can't configure the background to be completely transparent 
using JWPlayer version 5.9.

When setting screencolor to white, there is a white-grey gradient in the background,

This is my configuration code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer("container").setup({
    flashplayer: "jwPlayer/player.swf",
    file: "views/stylesheets/images/welocomeMovie.flv",
    autostart: true,
    controlbar: 'over',
    height: 200,
    width: 360,
    screencolor: 'FFFFFF'
    wmode : 'transparent',
  });
</script>
```

Do you have any idea how to make the background transparent?

Thanks,
Omri

Comment: Now it works with jwPlayer 5 [(example)](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/player/trunk/fl5/js/test/examples/wmode.html)

Answer (score 3):

screencolor: 'FFFFFF'
wmode : 'transparent',

you comma should be before after screencolor:'FFFFFF'